Fourier transform of an invariant measure on a compact group
I consider $G$ a compact group and $\mu\in M^{1}(G)$ so that $\lvert\mu\rvert < \infty$ which is translation invariant. I want to show that for all nontrivial character $\chi$ we have $\hat{\mu}(\chi)=0$ where $\hat{\mu}(\chi) = \int_{G}\chi(g)d\mu(g)$.
My attempt is the following and do not use the convolution property which my book does, so I would like to know where is the possible mistake please:
Since $\chi$ is bounded by $1$ we have $\lvert\hat{\mu}(\chi)\rvert\leq\lvert\mu(G)\rvert<\infty$. Now, since $\chi$ is nontrivial, there exists $g_1\in G$ such that $\chi(g_1)\neq 1$, however using the translation invariance of $\mu$ we have
$$
\hat{\mu}(\chi) = \int_{G}\chi(g)d\mu(g) = \int_{G}\chi(g + g_1)d\mu(g) = \int_{G}\chi(g)\chi(g_1)d\mu(g)=\chi(g_1)\hat{\mu}(\chi)
$$
since $\hat{\mu}(\chi)$ is a finite quantity, we must have $\hat{\mu}(\chi)=0$.
